# Premiere Pro - Edit a video with different scenes - Use sequences or not?

Tags: premiere-pro

I have to edit a short movie (10 min long), made of several short scenes. Each scene has multiple takes and clips that need to be edited.

I was wondering, which is the best/most efficient option:

1. Working with sequences, having one sequence for each scene, and work on each scene independently, and then merge all sequences in one at the end
2. Having all the scenes in just one sequence, and editing them together one after the other?

What is more efficient?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say neither:

I'd work on small parts in separate sequences until I'm fairly happy with them, then start to bring them into a main sequence, by copying them in using the lift control.  I don't nest sequences, because I always end up finding the lack of control in the master sequence becomes a problem.

If there are multiple cameras within a single take, I'd use mutli-camera sequences to sync those up first.

A key part of working like this is organising and reviewing takes rather than how you edit in Premiere - careful labelling of footage and a good spreadsheet is essential in my opinion!

(Also really important to duplicate your sequences, so you can go back and retry different ideas, whilst labelling them carefully throughout)